# how to parse nested table usin jsoup

Tags: jsoup

How can I extract "tr" tags which has directly two "td" tags using jsoup.

sample html

```
<table>
  <tr> <!-- I don't want to extract this tr -->
    <td> 
      <table>
        <tr><td>extract</td><td>extract</td></tr> <!-- I want extact this tr -->
        <tr><td>extract</td><td>extract</td></tr> <!-- I want extact this tr -->
      </table>      
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I tried to extract using this query. but I had got 3 tr tags.

```
doc.select("tr:has(td:eq(1))")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried following query `doc.select("tr tr")` ?

this query should select all table rows which you commented.

Comment: Yes, I have. I want to extract tr that has 2 td directly. I dont want to extract 2nd tr.

Comment: ok, now i understand your problem ;) sorry but i don't think, that a lookahead like for regex is possible in jsoup selectors. so it is easy to select the td elements, but i found no selector which returns the parent of this result. therefor it seems the only possible solution would be to select the parent through the api of the result.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried the following code, but i got 3 tr tags. So I will request a new feature like "hasOwn".

Answer (score 1):

// I hope this will help u........u can see output like that : a  b   c   d  /n e  f   g   h that are stored in td tags of inner table.

```
       String input = "<table><tr><td >TD1</td><td>td1</td> <td ><table><tr><td >a</td><td>b</td> <td >c</td><td>d</td></tr><tr><td>e</td><td>f</td><td >g</td><td>h</td></tr></table></td><td>td1</td></tr><tr><td>TD2</td><td>tD2</td><td >Td2</td><td>td2</td></tr></table>";

     Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input);

    Elements tables = doc.select("table tr td:has(table)");

    for (Element table : tables) {

        Elements trs = table.select("tr");

        String[][] trtd = new String[trs.size()][];

        for (int a = 0; a < trs.size(); a++) {

            Elements tds = trs.get(a).select("td");

            trtd[a] = new String[tds.size()];

            for (int b = 0; b < tds.size(); b++) {

                trtd[a][b] = tds.get(b).text(); 

              System.out.print( trtd[a][b] +"    ");

            }
          System.out.println( );
        }

        // trtd now contains the desired array for this table
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome and thanks for the additional answer! However consider explaining what the code does (possibly through inline comments) and how it solves the problem.

Comment: can also use doc.select("td:has(table)"). it only selects  td tags that contain table tags and it can extract the values of td tags of selected table and store in array. each row output is divided by "/n". I think it can solve the problem what the questionnaire wanted directly...